# Background color and rubber-band scrolling in Mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, scroll, ios9, mobile-safari

I'm building a webpage in Mobile Safari with a fixed header/footer and rubber-band scrolling in the main content:

```css
 html,
 body {
   margin: 0 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
 }
 .header,
 .footer {
   height: 50px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 100;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .header {
   top: 0;
   background-color: #44677F;
 }
 .footer {
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #4E3AFF;
 }
 .container {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
 .content {
   background-size: 50px 50px;
   background-color: #D0FCFF;
   background-image: linear-gradient(#9DC9FF 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
   height: 2000px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header"></header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I can change the background color of the area visible during the rubber-band scrolling?

I'd like use the same colors of the header/footer, so that when I scroll up:

[image: header]

and when I scroll down:

[image: footer]

I know that is possible to change the entire color of the scrolling areas by setting a background color in the body:

```
.body {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

so I tried to use a gradient:

```
.body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #44677F 50%, #4E3AFF 50%);
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Scrolling is an event thus CSS can't change a background when scrolling. However you can do this using JQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) API

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz I'm happy to use JavaScript if that's the only way to solve this problem. Although I would prefer not to use jQuery.

Comment: I'm using my phone on the bus right now so I can't be much help at the moment. [here's](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#42bd3465730905bf15f71b6d1bf9101b) a weave I mocked up to show you how to handle styling using JQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Comment: why dont u try browsersatck..and simulate Iphone there..and then inspect element for such behaviour.??

Answer (score 3):

One way you could achieve this is by adding fixed elements behind your content, one element for the top and one for the bottom with the same background colors as your header/footer.

```
#headerBackground {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #{headerColor}
}
#footerBackground {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #{footerColor}
}
<body>
  <div id="footerBackground "></div>
  <div id="headerBackground "></div>
  <header class="header"></header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

You may need to play around with z-index to get thing to be behind the header/footer.