# Modifying what's shown beyond the actual page

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

On many modern browsers (for example both Safari and Chrome on MacOS and iOS), it's possible to scroll past the actual html page to explore what lies beyond it (for example, on this very page, there's a white field below the dark footer on the bottom). I've been trying to figure out the general principle behind how to modify these areas.

Specifying a background color of the `body` element in CSS makes it possible to choose a unified look for everything that's outside the actual page, but this doesn't work if one wants different things to show up at different places (for example, on this very page, it would be natural for the footer color to extend to the left and to the right only *below* its own border, but not above where the obvious choice would be white).

So, how should one approach modifying the content outside of the actual page (that is, content that's not really existing/being shown on certain browsers)?

Comment: I created a video to show people what I'm talking about: https://youtu.be/ihtw461YF8I

Comment: Any suggestions on how to better word my question is highly appreciated. I'm not looking for a specific answer to a specific problem. I'm looking for a toolbox that can be applied to many different problems having to do with the same thing. That is, if I were to ask how I could modify my page depending on the users device, the answer would be a short crash course in responsive web design and a link to a good tutorial where I could find out more. I want the equivalent of that, pertaining to my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

> for example, on this very page, there's a white field below the dark footer on the bottom

Are you talking about what e.g. Safari on iOS does when you scroll beyond the page? Because most browsers don't do what you describe.

What Safari on iOS does is indeed using some heuristics like background-color of the `<body>` and `<html>` tags (and possibly other elements). This behavior is not standardized, since traditionally browsers would never scroll the page further than to the bottom.

It cannot really be customized that much, but [there's an approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924410/background-color-and-rubber-band-scrolling-in-mobile-safari).

Comment: Oh, is this about the snap to thing that safari does on iOS? How it scrolls beyond the page and then snaps back? That would make this make so much more sense, haha.

Comment: Well, for example both Safari and Chrome does this on both MacOS and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

In almost every scenario imaginable, you won't be able to view anything below the end of the `<body>` element (except for the example @mb21 pointed out). So in theory, any background style applied to the body will be visible to the very bottom of the viewport. Generally speaking, a background colour won't extend outside of its container.

Comment: Well, it happens all the time if you're using MacOS or iOS; both Safari and Chrome are displaying this behavior (I don't know the story on Windows). I wouldn't consider this an edge case at all.